# How To Rescue Referenced Photos - Originals are no longer available to me

Tags: macos, photos, data-recovery

- I have a very large collection of Photos in the Apple Photos App.
  Through my own carelessness, I have several thousand photos that are
  not stored in the .photoslibrary file and the originals no longer
  exist anywhere (Time Machine, Backups, etc.)
- I can still view the Photos within the Photos app but I cannot Print, Edit, Drag them to
  the desktop, Share them, etc.
- I have copied my .photolibrary file,
  revealed the package contents and imported all of the images stored
  in the masters and derivatives folder/subfolder. The photos I'm
  trying to rescue are not among them.
- There has to be a way to
  rescue these images short of taking a screenshot of each one. Photos
  is retrieving them from somewhere to display them, but I cannot
  discern where to find them.
- I've attached a screenshot of the
  message I get when I try and perform an edit on a single image.

[image: Referenced Photo Error Message]

Comment: Photos derives thumbnail and proxy versions of most images, so those are what are shown on screen. Hopefully a library repair and/or [using a tool like PowerPhotos](https://fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/) can help merge old libraries and sort out the actual image sizes of the proxies if you choose to import them and can’t locate the full source images in backups.